# Add custom Javascript <script> tags to Napili and Lightning communities after Summer 17 release

Tags: javascript, lightning, community, locker-service, napili

After Summer 17 release the LockerService will disable Javascript  tags in the community Header Markup and access to DOM from Lightning Components. If I would like to add a custom Javascript to Napili and Lightning community that could access the page and DOM what are the options if any?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Normally, I am able to create a custom Lightning component to implement my custom logic without issues. Do you really need to have access to the whole page? Outside your own components?

Comment: @rumdumdum you never got back the Marc-Antoines question, What are you trying to achieve and how?

Comment: How about dropping a dummy component and accessing window object from it?